# Python: _socket.so

Tags: python, sockets, ftp

Greetings!

So I'm creating a Python script that will when finished be compiled with Shedskin. Currently we do a little FTP work in this script so we import the ftplib module. When I attempt to compile it with Shedskin we get the error back saying that there is no '_socket' file in our Python2.6 installation on Ubuntu. I've checked myself in the '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload' dir to confirm that yes there isn't any file entitled '_socket.so' present in that folder.

I've tried reinstalling the python2.6 package in Synaptic but to no avail.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Look for `shdeskin` supported library modules in
`/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/shedskin/lib/`.

My Fedora installation of `shdeskin 0.7` does not include `ftplib`.